# cURL display remote image using http (no https), and specific port, with PHP

Tags: php, http, curl

The scenario is like this:
there is a single image, hosted on a remote server, that is **not** using https AND opens the 8088 port.
Such image must be displayed on a website (https, shared hosting, latest php, latest cURL).

Being on a http, anything done via js returns error.
So I thought that cURL could be a solution, and that is my actual code:

```
//header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

$ch = curl_init('http://1.2.3.4:8088/snap.jpeg');
$fp = fopen('snap.jpeg', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.1 Safari/537.11');
curl_exec($ch);

echo curl_errno($ch);
echo curl_error($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);


/*
$url = 'http://1.2.3.4:8088/snap.jpeg';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.1 Safari/537.11');
$res = curl_exec($ch);
$rescode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch) ;
echo $res;


$url = 'http://1.2.3.4:8088/snap.jpeg';
$img = 'snap1.jpeg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));

*/
```

As you can see I already done some tests to handle that problem.
If I browse to that url with a browser, the image shows up in a second, just the download time, while all the test above returns a timeout error (both curls and file_get_contents)

```
28Failed to connect to 1.2.3.4 port 8088: Connection timed out
```

is something I cannot bypass? I mean, that image will be over http, and not https, I cannot change anything on that side, and I'm on a shared serer (so the capabilities are very limited, and I cannot install anything).

I don't even want to talk about putting an iframe on the site, I have not tested it and cannot be a solution :D
Any idea?
Thanks in advance, ask for any information.

Comment: Your web server can't access "1.2.3.4", is it behind a firewall? Is it perhaps not a "remote server" but rather, one on your own local network? As a side note, it's probably easier to proxy the image by editing your [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) or [Apache](https://serverfault.com/a/825289) configuration.

Comment: the website weserver should be behind a firewall, but actually I can cURL pretty anything from there.
I cannot edit any configuration, because I'm on a shared host.
The ip is remote and visible on internet, and it is accessible via browser using the same url.